# How to analyse file on linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a file in the following format:

> {"report":[{"call_time":"2018-03-31 00:10:13","number":"01232802624","CLI":"7941232455","name":null,"destination":null,"status":"Answered","duration":"27:30"},
>   {"call_time":"2018-03-31 00:12:21","number":"01233802632","CLI":"7831233003","name":null,"destination":null,"status":"Answered","duration":"7:48"},
>   {"call_time":"2018-03-31 00:51:16","number":"0123802642","CLI":"7711123367","name":null,"destination":null,"status":"Answered","duration":"0:57"},
>   {"call_time":"2018-03-31 01:50:33","number":"012342802624","CLI":"7812386544","name":null,"destination":null,"status":"Answered","duration":"9:54"},
>   {"call_time":"2018-03-31 16:29:38","number":"01232802642","CLI":"7741230002","name":null,"destination":null,"status":"Answered","duration":"0:13"}],
>   "summary":{"Total_Calls":"3,862","Answered_Calls":"3,834","Answered":"3,922:58","Calls_Answered":"99.1%","ACD":"8:00"},"result":1}

I need to filter out all but the latest ten lines for each "number" (ideally the latest 10 items timewise), and print an average duration.

Expected output is something like:

```
2018-03-31 00:10:13 01232802624 27:30
01232802624 Average 27:30

2018-03-31 00:12:21 01233802632 7:48
01233802632 Average 7:48

2018-03-31 00:51:16 0123802642 0:57
2018-03-31 16:29:38 0123802642 0:13
0123802642 Average: 0:30
```

etc

Any thoughts welcome... I've tried for hours using sed, grep and awk and cannot do this... my code and results are all over the place. I'm struggling to find any solution online.

Comment: Please show us expected output in code tags too in your post.

Comment: Still not clear, wrap your samples in code tags by using {} button in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a powerful tool for processing JSON. It has good documentation available at [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

jq's support for parsing durations is a bit lacking so you'll probably have to use something else there, and also I'm not sure about the exact output format you want, so I haven't given a complete solution.

Here is an example, perhaps it helps push you in the right direction:

```
$ jq '.report | group_by(.number) | .[][-10:] | [.] | map({number: .[0].number, calls: map({call_time: .call_time, duration: .duration})}) | .[]' < data
{
  "number": "01232802624",
  "calls": [
    {
      "call_time": "2018-03-31 00:10:13",
      "duration": "27:30"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "number": "01232802642",
  "calls": [
    {
      "call_time": "2018-03-31 16:29:38",
      "duration": "0:13"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "number": "01233802632",
  "calls": [
    {
      "call_time": "2018-03-31 00:12:21",
      "duration": "7:48"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "number": "012342802624",
  "calls": [
    {
      "call_time": "2018-03-31 01:50:33",
      "duration": "9:54"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "number": "0123802642",
  "calls": [
    {
      "call_time": "2018-03-31 00:51:16",
      "duration": "0:57"
    }
  ]
}
```

Explained:

1. `.report`: Take the `report` key of the root object
2. `group_by(.number)`: group by the value of the `number` key
3. `.[][-10:]`: for each group (`.[]`), keep only the last 10 items (`[-10:]`)
4. `[.]`: nest in an array to make the next command happy
5. `map(...)`: map the array of groups to an array of objects
6. `.[]` remove unnecessary nesting

---

Here is another variant, with output tab-separated:

```
$ jq -r '.report | group_by(.number) | .[][-10:] | map([.number, .call_time, .duration]) | .[], [] | join("\t")' < data
01232802624 2018-03-31 00:10:13 27:30

01232802642 2018-03-31 16:29:38 0:13

01233802632 2018-03-31 00:12:21 7:48

012342802624    2018-03-31 01:50:33 9:54

0123802642  2018-03-31 00:51:16 0:57
```

Explained:

1. `.report`: Take the `report` key of the root object
2. `group_by(.number)`: group by the value of the `number` key
3. `.[][-10:]`: for each group (`.[]`), keep only the last 10 items (`[-10:]`)
4. `map(...)`: map the objects to array items
5. `.[], []`: add an additional array to create space between the groups
6. `join("\t")`: join the elements of each array with tabs

Comment: Thank you - that's excellent! It's almost there - just a tabular or column format so it can be reviewed would make it complete... I'll play with jq to see if I can figure that step out - if you happen to know it, it would help.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add an example where the output is tab-delimted.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the time to write entire script but this can be done with simple script:

1. List your numbers: awk on 7th field then sort then uniq.
2. Select 10 last lines for each: loop on last result with a grep and tail -10
3. Convert duration in seconds for results found.
4. Do subtotal and an average duration.
5. Then print.

Hope this help